# Clean existing cookies?

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookies

If you look for "clean tracking cookies" on google, you find exclusively instructions how to nuke ALL cookies and/or how to install tracking protection extensions. Now perhaps this is intentional sabotage by Google.

What I'm trying to find is a tool that kills existing tracking cookies, e.g. you sometimes have to disable firefox tracking protection to make a given website work. In e.g. Heidi SQL editor web page the download link won't work if you don't. This will enable multiple tracking cookies to be set, which will then sit there even if Firefox blocks new ones from being set.

So, is there a stand alone tool or an extension that could take e.g. Adguard tracking cookie list and wipe out any existing cookies that match the rules? Bonus if such exists for Android which does open links in apps constantly, no doubt accumulating hundreds of tracking cookies in the process.

Comment: Another option would be to use a `hosts` file to prevent the tracking traffic, however, I wouldn't rely on this alone and would use both the `hosts` file from [MVPS](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm), while also removing the tracking cookies

Comment: You could probably also use an external blocker like adguard, I'm testing it in Android right now. I should actually figure out how to clean cookies the apps accumulate since they open links in some kind of embedded browser, not the browser defined in Android settings.

Comment: You may want to move this to the [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site, as doing this on Android vs a PC is not the same.  For example, unless you're rooted, you can't modify your `hosts` file [`/system/etc/hosts`]

Comment: I'm looking for a PC tool, something like ccleaner does wipe out all cookies but it doesn't apply any kind of rules to do it. For Android, adguard acts as a VPN.

Comment: The simplest way to do what you want is to use a custom `hosts` file that blocks known tracking IPs _(which the MVPS link in my first comment provides)_; otherwise, you'll need to manually edit the `cookies` SQL database: `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cookies`.  The [Privacy Badger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/privacy-badger/pkehgijcmpdhfbdbbnkijodmdjhbjlgp) and [Comodo UAdBlocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/comodo-uadblocker/hhnkmoijlinhobdagnchdhogdmedamce) extensions would also be recommended

Comment: Those will *prevent* cookies, I'm trying to find a way to *selectively delete* existing cookies.

Comment: You will need to manually edit the SQL database `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cookies`